# What is a query operator tree in a database

Tags: database, database-design

What is a query operator tree in a database engine and what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a database engine (particularly an SQL-based engine) runs a query, it actually breaks down the query into little steps.  Filter a bit here, join a table there, etc.  A query operator tree is basically a representation of those steps.